# max operation for selective elements, not for all

Tags: pytorch, max

I am coding PyTorch. Between the torch inference code, I add some peripheral code for my own interest. This code works fine, but it is too slow. The reason might be for iteration. So, i need parallel and fast way of doing this.

It is okay to do this in tensor, Numpy, or just python array.

I made a function named `selective_max` to find maximum value in arrays. But the problem is that I don't want a maximum among the whole arrays, but among specific candidates which is designated by `mask` array. Let me show the gist of this function (below shows the code itself)

## Input

`x [batch_size , dim, num_points, k]` : x is a original input, but this becomes [batch_size, num_points, dim, k] by `x.permute(0,2,1,3)`.

`batch_size` is a well-known definition in the deep learning society. In every mini batch, there are many points. And a single point is represented by `dim` length feature. For each feature element, there are `k` potential candidates which is target of `max` function later.

`mask [batch_size, num_points, k]` : This array is similar to `x` without `dim`. Its element is either `0` or `1`. So, I use this as a mask signal, like do max operation only on `1` masked value.

Kindly see the code below with this explanation. I use `3` for iteration. Let's say we target a specific batch and a specific point. For a specific batch and a specific point, `x` has [dim, k] array. And mask has [k] array which consists of either `0` or `1`. So, I extract the non-zero index from [k] array and use this for extracting specific elements in `x` dim by dim('for k in range(dim)').

## Toy example

Let's say we are in the second for iteration. So, we now have `[dim, k]` for `x` and `[k]` for `mask`. For this toy example, `i` presume `k=3` and `dim=4`. `x = [[3,2,1],[5,6,4],[9,8,7],[12,11,10]]`, `k=[0,1,1]`. So, output would be `[2,6,8,11]`, not `[3, 6, 9, 12]`.

## Previous attempt

I try `{ mask.repeat(0,0,1,0) *(element-wise mul) x }` and do the `max` operation. But, '0' might the max value, because the x might have minus values in all array. So, this would result in wrong operation.

```
def selective_max2(x, mask): # x : [batch_size , dim, num_points, k] , mask : [batch_size, num_points, k]
batch_size = x.size(0)
dim = x.size(1)
num_points = x.size(2)
k = x.size(3)
device = torch.device('cuda')

x = x.permute(0,2,1,3) # : [batch, num_points, dim, k]
#print('permuted x dimension : ',x.size())

x = x.detach().cpu().numpy()
mask = mask.cpu().numpy()
output = np.zeros((batch_size,num_points,dim))

for i in range(batch_size):
 for j in range(num_points):
  query=np.nonzero(mask[i][j]) # among mask entries, we get the index of nonzero values.
  for k in range(dim): # for different k values, we get the max value.
   # query is index of nonzero values. so, using query, we can get the values that we want.
   output[i][j][k] = np.max(x[i][j][k][query])

output = torch.from_numpy(output).float().to(device=device)
output = output.permute(0,2,1).contiguous()
return output
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I've followed your toy example (however while retaining generality) to write the following solution.*

The first thing is to [expand your `k` as `x`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand_as) (treating them both as [PyTorch tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)):

```
k_expanded = k.expand_as(x)
```

Then you select the elements where your `1`'s exist in the `k_expanded`, and [view](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) the resulting tensor as `x` number of rows (written as `x.shape[0]`), and number of `1`'s in `k` (or the mask) as the number of columns. Up to this point, we have selected the range we want to query the maximum element for. Then, you find the maximum along the rows dimension (showed in [`.sum(0)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sum.html#torch.sum)) using [`max(1)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html#torch.max)

```
values, indices = x[k_expanded == 1].view(x.shape[0], (k == 1).sum(0)).max(1)
values
Out[29]: tensor([ 2,  6,  8, 11])
```

**Benchmarks**

```
def find_max_elements_inside_tensor_range(arr, mask, return_indices=False):
    mask_expanded = mask.expand_as(arr)
    values, indices = x[k_expanded==1].view(x.shape[0], (k == 1).sum(0)).max(1)
    return (values, indices) if return_indices else values
```

Just added a third parameter in case you want to get the numbers indices

```
%timeit find_max_elements_inside_tensor_range(x, k)
38.4 µs ± 534 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

*Note: the above solution also works for tensors and masks of various shapes.*